# Does Flyway have s.th. like dbmaintain's "markDatabaseAsUpToDate" (maven-)task?

Tags: flyway

Our common workflow when creating a new sql migration script is
to write and execute every single statement in the developers local datatase schema. When finished, it's checked into the source control system.
Problem is: at the database scheme of the creating developer, the script is already "executed". For scripts not beeing reentrant - it would be convenient to have s.th. like Dbmaintain's maven task "markDatabaseAsUpToDatemaven".

Does Flyway have s.th. equivalent?

P.S.: Our current workflow (as a workaround) is as follows:

1. "mvn flyway:migrate" this file as an empty file (without content - so it never fails).
2. put the sql statments in, save & "migrate" again.
3. "mvn flyway:repair"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While the workflow you describe sounds like it can do the job, you can achieve the same in a simpler and fully automated way: set `cleanOnValidationError` to `true` (on for dev!) and everytime the script changes, the DB gets recreated.

More info: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/migrate.html#cleanOnValidationError

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Unfortunately it is not an option for us to "clean" the db. The local db schema is not empty (filled with data for development and local testing). As I already wrote: I was looking for feature to mark the flyway meta data as "up to date" (in sense of the currently existing sql migration scripts): "as they would have been already successfully executed".